# Test if var is of a union type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to test if var man is of type person in a test function, but it does output both person and animal, so what's the right way ?

```
    class Man {}
    class Woman {}
    class Cat {}
    class Dog {}
    type Person = Man | Woman;
    type Animal = Cat | Dog;

    function test(entity: Person | Animal) {
        if (entity as Person) {
            console.log('person')
        }
        if (entity as Animal) {
            console.log('animal')
        }
    }

    let man = new Man();

    test(man);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types get removed when compiling, so anything you want to check at runtime you use standard javascript for. Your current code, once the types are removed, is just:

```
if (entity) {
  console.log('person')
}
```

So you're just checking if entity is truthy (not `null`, not `undefined`, not `0`, not an empty string, etc)

Instead, you could use instanceof:

```
if (entity instanceof Man || entity instanceof Woman) {
  console.log('person')
}
```

Or if the classes have some distinguishing property on them you could check that.

```
class Man { isPerson = true }
class Woman { isPerson = true }
class Cat { isPerson = false }
class Dog { isPerson = false }

// ...
if (entity.isPerson) {
  console.log('person')
}
```

Comment: I'm upset they didn't add a feature for this: I wanted to avoid enumerating all the sub-types ;)